# A very simple question about inequalities involving functions.

Tags: calculus, functions, partial-derivative

Say I have a function

$$f: \Pi \rightarrow \Phi$$

where $\Pi \subset \mathbb{R^2}, \Phi \subset \mathbb{R}$

If I were to say that $f \leq 0$ on $\partial\Pi$, then can I say

- $M \leq 0$ OR
- $M = 0$

Where $M$ is the maximum of $f$ on the boundary.

What I am getting at is that $f$ is less than OR equal to 0 on the boundary therefore it's maximum could be zero or possibly less.

This seems like an incredibly stupid question that I should know the answer to.

Comment: $f(\partial \Pi) \subset \mathbb{R}^2$, what does it mean $f < 0$?

Comment: Yes, sorry about that.

Comment: You mean the maximum of $f(\Pi)$ or the maximum of $f(\partial \Pi)$?

Comment: Maximum of $f(\partial \Pi)$, that is the maximum of $f$ on the boundary? (just so we are on the same page).

Comment: In this case you're right. Because $f(\partial \Pi) \le 0 $, its maximum must be no larger than 0

Comment: So the first bullet point is correct?

Comment: The first one is correct